# Calculate $\int {\frac{{\sqrt {x + 1} - \sqrt {x - 1} }}{{\sqrt {x + 1} + \sqrt {x - 1} }}} dx $

Tags: integration

Calculate
$$\int {\frac{{\sqrt {x + 1}  - \sqrt {x - 1} }}{{\sqrt {x + 1}  + \sqrt {x - 1} }}} dx
$$

My try:

$$\int {\frac{{\sqrt {x + 1}  - \sqrt {x - 1} }}{{\sqrt {x + 1}  + \sqrt {x - 1} }}} dx = \left| {x + 1 = {u^2}} \right| = 2\int {\frac{{(u - \sqrt { - 2 + {u^2}} )}}{{u + \sqrt { - 2 + {u^2}} }}du} 
$$

I tried to do first Euler substitute:

$$\sqrt { - 2 + {u^2}}  = {u_1} - u
$$

But it did not lead me to the goal. Any thoughts will be appriciated.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and the denominator by the numerator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

$$\left (\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1} \right )\left (\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1} \right ) = 2$$

Then the integral is

$$\frac12 \int dx \, \left (\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1} \right )^2$$

which is

$$\int dx \left (x -  \sqrt{x^2-1}\right ) $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: (↑) As it happened, I posted more or less the same answer as you. I've deleted mine...

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}}\,dx &=& \int\frac{2x-2\sqrt{x^2-1}}{2}\,dx\\ &=&\; C+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2-1}+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right).\end{eqnarray*}$$